# Interview: Collections Iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Hi guys i got this as an interview question and was having trouble with it. I am familiar with generics/collections & iterator but the manner i which the Collection is declared completely threw me.

Heres the question: Contained in the provided workspace is cocI, the start of a class that implements an Iterator that can be used to iterate a Collection of Collections. The Collection of Collections is passed into the constructor of the class. The Iterator should iterate through the contents depth-first.

For example, if the Collection of Collections looks like the following:

```
[0] – [“A”, “B”, “C”] 
[1] – [“D”] 
[2] – [“E”, “F”]
```

The iterator should then return the contents in the following order: “A”, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, “F”

Q.Provide implementations for the hasNext() and next() methods in cocI

Thanks

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class cocI implements Iterator<Object> {

    private Collection<Collection<Object>> _collOfColl = null;

    public cocI(Collection<Collection<Object>> collofColl) {
        _collOfColl = collofColl;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO implement this method
        return false;
    }


    public Object next() {
        // TODO implement this method
        return null;
    }


    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327077/interview-design-an-iterator-for-a-collection-of-collections

Comment: Or perhaps this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163889/how-to-implement-iterator-on-nested-collection-in-java

Comment: hi nikhil, the main problem I am having is the line 'private Collection<Collection<Object>> _collOfColl = null;'  I understand how to iterate through a normal collection and use the has next & next methods. why is the above line not ''private Collection<Object> _collOfColl = null;' ??

Comment: I had read them already but will check them out again, thanks

Comment: `Collection<Object>` would be a one-dimensional Collection of objects. `Collection<Collection<Object>>` is - as the question states - a Collection of Collections. That is, it is a Collection that has inside of it several Collections, each made up of Objects. Did this make it any clearer?

Comment: Asking us to do your interview question for you is morally suspect, to say the least. I'm pretty sure your potential employer is trying to gauge _your_ skills, not those of the SO audience.

Comment: Hi yshavit, Just to make it clear the interview was yesterday which i failed so this is for my learning purposes only.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. A lot of companies have take-home interviews, which is what I thought this was from the phrasing. My apologies, and kudos for taking steps to learn!

Comment: yeah thanks MLV thats after clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of introductory remarks:

- `cocI` is an odd class name; it should start with a capital letter.
- The interface you are supposed to implement doesn't use generics effectively.  You should be able to use a data type more specific than `Object`.
- It is good practice to use the `@Override` annotation.

The solution involves an iterator for the outer collection and an iterator for the inner collection.  When the inner iterator runs out of elements, it needs to be replaced with an iterator for the next collection.  However, considering that a collection could be empty, the advancement needs to be done in a loop, which I've put in an `advanceCollection()` helper.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class cocI<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private Iterator<Collection<T>> outerIterator;
    private Iterator<T> innerIterator;

    public cocI(Collection<Collection<T>> collofColl) {
        this.outerIterator = collofColl.iterator();
        advanceCollection();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.innerIterator != null && this.innerIterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (this.innerIterator == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        try {
            return this.innerIterator.next();
        } finally {
            advanceCollection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private void advanceCollection() {
        while ((this.innerIterator == null || !this.innerIterator.hasNext())
               && this.outerIterator.hasNext()) {
            this.innerIterator = this.outerIterator.next().iterator();
        }
    }

}
```

---

There is one slightly tricky piece of code I used:

```
    try {
        return this.innerIterator.next();
    } finally {
        advanceCollection();
    }
```

It is roughly equivalent to:

```
    T result = this.innerIterator.next();
    advanceCollection();
    return result;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the anwser 200_success.  Will also take on board your remarks

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is keep track of the current collection's iterator within the collection of collections. The `hasnext()` method, which is the tricky part, will then do one of two things: return true if the current iterator has more elements, if not search until we find a collection that has elements. If we exhaust all the collections, return false.

```
public class Cocl implements Iterator<Object> {

    private Collection<Collection<Object>> _collOfColl = null;
    private final Iterator<Collection<Object>> coClIterator;
    private Iterator<Object> currentColIterator;

    public Cocl(Collection<Collection<Object>> collofColl) {
        _collOfColl = collofColl;
        coClIterator = collofColl.iterator();
        if (coClIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentColIterator = coClIterator.next().iterator();
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (currentColIterator == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!currentColIterator.hasNext()) {
            while (coClIterator.hasNext()) {
                currentColIterator = coClIterator.next().iterator();
                if (currentColIterator.hasNext()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            return currentColIterator.next();
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }


    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Object> one = Arrays.asList((Object) "A", (Object) "B", (Object) "C");
        Collection<Object> two = Arrays.asList((Object) "D", (Object) "E");
        Cocl cocl = new Cocl(Arrays.asList(one, two));
        while (cocl.hasNext()) {
            Object a = cocl.next();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no need to store `_collOfColl` at all.

Comment: No, it's just that OP's template contained it.

Comment: Since you are aready checking if there is at least one collection in the constructor, one should probably add a null check to the first idf statement in `hasNext` to avoid NPE in the corner case of having an empty collection of collections.